# Resetting margin and padding for everything in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to reset the margin and padding for all elements on my pages, so that all the elements that usually come with default padding and margin don't have any. Usually I would do this like

```
*{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

But this doesn't work in WordPress so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite difficult to say anything without seeing your code, But you could try this:

```
* {
    padding: 0!important;
    margin: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: This is one of the few times `!important` is acceptable, if you really wish to enforce the 0 padding and margin for *every* element.

Comment: Sir he wants to reset the margin and padding for all elements

Comment: Yes, which is what I stated right, this comment was ment as a constructive compliment :).

Comment: The only problem with this is that !important will overwrite any padding or margin I do wish to add later.

Comment: Could be solved by also using !important with a higher specifity. Or use a reset.css